# phraseapp and rails 5 loading assets

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails 5 app.
When I load a page I get

> Started GET
>   "/assets/application-45dde04378a57c22899ad2b31fae609166d231a52227d7095836a8496b6ab8f6.css" for ::1 at 2016-04-17 15:00:02 +0300 Started GET
>   "/assets/application-105f770c1dac6612cb5efcf55c5a7c64f9115638cbc3e851f6423f55bea5f5f6.js"
>   for ::1 at 2016-04-17 15:00:02 +0300

When I add phraseapp gem

```
gem 'phraseapp-in-context-editor-ruby', '~> 1.0.4'
```

I get

> Started GET "/stylesheets/application.css" for ::1 at 2016-04-17
>   15:00:12 +0300 Started GET "/javascripts/application.js" for ::1 at
>   2016-04-17 15:00:12 +0300

and the page loads without the css and JS.
Can you please help??

Comment: Hmm might need to give us a bit more background.  What are you trying to achieve? What are your thoughts/guesses so far as to what might be happening? What is the error stopping from happening?

Comment: with the gem the app loads without css or js. This is not good. I want to load it with them. My guess is the problem is rails 5 because I have another rails 4 app that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more work than you want to do, but it's good practice for if you get stuck on problems like this.

Make a new rails app, install this gem and see if you can reproduce the issue.

The good news if you can is that you can pop up your demo app on github and then share it here and also post an issue on the official github project (https://github.com/phrase/phraseapp-in-context-editor-ruby).

Give that a go, there is just not enough info right now to help out, it does just sound like maybe this gem does not yet support rails 5. Doing it this way you're doing your bit to help open source also.

Comment: Long shot, just checking the basics, double check you have followed all the instructions on their README. https://github.com/phrase/phraseapp-in-context-editor-ruby. Just thinking out loud maybe maybe one of the security steps there needs to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put this lines in application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'javascripts')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Comment: To clarify, did you put this in application.rb or assets.rb? I